# How to prove that $\sqrt{n}(\ln S_n-\mu)$ converges in law to $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ where$S_n$is the logarithm of geometric mean of some iid $X_i$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ be some positive random variables, independent and identically distributed with $(\ln{X_n})^2$ integrable, $\textbf{E}[\ln X_n]=\mu$ and $\textbf{Var}[\ln{X_n}]=\sigma^2$. Define the geometric mean $S_n=(X_1X_2\dots X_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. We want to prove that $\sqrt{n}(\ln S_n-\mu)$ converges in law to $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. My guess is that this is an application of $Lindeberg$'s CLT. However, I wasn't able to prove the condition.

Comment: This is the classical CLT (Lindeberg-Lévy).  What condition are you talking about?

Comment: Let $Y_n=\ln X_n$ and rewrite the question as "Let $Y_n$ be some random variable ... We want to prove $\sqrt{n}(\bar Y -\mu)$ ..."  You need independence

Comment: I computed the Variances of $\ln S_n$ to be $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Can I apply the classical CLT with that? or maybe I made a mistake

Comment: I'm talking about the Lindeberg's condition.

Comment: The Lindeberg/Lyapunov conditions are needed when the random variables you're summing are not identically distributed.  Here they are iid, so it's purely classical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{n}(\ln S_n-\mu)=\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_i-\mu)$ and $\ln X_i$ i.i.d. r.v.s, and the result follows from CLT, i.e.
it converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, since Var[$\ln X_i]=\sigma^2$.

Comment: You may be missing a $\frac1n$ inside the brackets